# d3 transition between time groupings

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, time-series

I can't seem to find a simple example where a chart can easily bounce between time grouping levels. Say I have daily data, and I want the ability to display this data on a chart at different levels of aggregation (daily, weekly, monthly).

Is there a good way to do this with D3 without a lot of processing (removing all rects, and replacing with new rects grouped at a different level)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

d3 has a general update pattern that you should use for this case.

The convention is to have two functions, one to setup the visualization, and another to take data and update the visualization.

The update function takes in the new data, binds it, updates existing svg's (rects in your case) and then adds or removes objects as necessary.

Mike Bostock has a great 3 part series explaining this which you can find here: https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/252496768267333632

Answer (score 0):

Since it's time series data, have you considered a [line/area chart with brushing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)? You could add UI components to dynamically set the brush filter to certain date ranges.